# The app forced to close when trying to upload picture to server

Tags: php, android

**I have copied this example from a website , I dont know why this is not working.**

My intended flow is: I am picking a picture from gallery, showing it inside imageview and then uploading it to server.

The first two step -picking a picture and showing it- was working fine but when I click on upload button then my app forcing to close i.e runtime error. I think there may be problem with php file, the way to use that but not sure.

You may ask for more info if required to solve my problem.

```
package com.example.imagepickanduplaod;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView image;
    private Button uploadButton;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Button selectImageButton;

    // number of images to select
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;

    /**
     * called when the activity is first created
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // find the views
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.uploadImage);
        uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);

        // on click select an image
        selectImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectImageButton);
        selectImageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectImageFromGallery();

            }
        });

        // when uploadButton is clicked
        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new ImageUploadTask().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Opens dialog picker, so the user can select image from the gallery. The
     * result is returned in the method <code>onActivityResult()</code>
     */
    public void selectImageFromGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    /**
     * Retrives the result returned from selecting image, by invoking the method
     * <code>selectImageFromGallery()</code>
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            decodeFile(picturePath);

        }
    }

    /**
     * The method decodes the image file to avoid out of memory issues. Sets the
     * selected image in to the ImageView.
     * 
     * @param filePath
     */
    public void decodeFile(String filePath) {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);

        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    /**
     * The class connects with server and uploads the photo
     * 
     * 
     */
    class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        private String webAddressToPost = "http://menaria.zz.mu/picupload.php";

        // private ProgressDialog dialog;
        private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(webAddressToPost);

                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                        HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
                String file = Base64.encodeBytes(data);
                entity.addPart("uploaded", new StringBody(file));

                entity.addPart("someOtherStringToSend", new StringBody(
                        "your string here"));

                httpPost.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                        localContext);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

                String sResponse = reader.readLine();
                return sResponse;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // something went wrong. connection with the server error
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file uploaded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    }
```

**And here is the stacktrace**

```
07-11 16:01:17.791: I/Timeline(27694): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@436a8d70 time:57708003
07-11 16:01:21.111: E/dalvikvm(27694): Could not find class 'org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity', referenced from method com.example.imagepickanduplaod.MainActivity$ImageUploadTask.doInBackground
07-11 16:01:21.111: W/dalvikvm(27694): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1607 (Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity;) in Lcom/example/imagepickanduplaod/MainActivity$ImageUploadTask;
07-11 16:01:21.111: D/dalvikvm(27694): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0011
07-11 16:01:21.111: I/dalvikvm(27694): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x14d2 at 0x13 in Lcom/example/imagepickanduplaod/MainActivity$ImageUploadTask;.doInBackground
07-11 16:01:21.111: D/dalvikvm(27694): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x3067 at 0x15 in Lcom/example/imagepickanduplaod/MainActivity$ImageUploadTask;.doInBackground
07-11 16:01:21.111: D/dalvikvm(27694): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x3069 at 0x36 in Lcom/example/imagepickanduplaod/MainActivity$ImageUploadTask;.doInBackground
07-11 16:01:21.111: D/dalvikvm(27694): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x3069 at 0x42 in Lcom/example/imagepickanduplaod/MainActivity$ImageUploadTask;.doInBackground
07-11 16:01:21.151: W/dalvikvm(27694): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f36d58)
07-11 16:01:21.151: E/AndroidRuntime(27694): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
07-11 16:01:21.151: E/AndroidRuntime(27694): Process: com.example.imagepickanduplaod, PID: 27694
07-11 16:01:21.151: E/AndroidRuntime(27694): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-11 16:01:21.151: E/AndroidRuntime(27694):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
07-11 16:01:21.151: E/AndroidRuntime(27694):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
07-11 16:01:21.151: E/AndroidRuntime(27694):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
07-11 16:01:21.151: E/AndroidRuntime(27694):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
07-11 16:01:21.151: E/AndroidRuntime(27694):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-11 16:01:21.151: E/AndroidRuntime(27694):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-11 16:01:21.151: E/AndroidRuntime(27694):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-11 16:01:21.151: E/AndroidRuntime(27694):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-11 16:01:21.151: E/AndroidRuntime(27694): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity
07-11 16:01:21.151: E/AndroidRuntime(27694):    at com.example.imagepickanduplaod.MainActivity$ImageUploadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:173)
07-11 16:01:21.151: E/AndroidRuntime(27694):    at com.example.imagepickanduplaod.MainActivity$ImageUploadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-11 16:01:21.151: E/AndroidRuntime(27694):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-11 16:01:21.151: E/AndroidRuntime(27694):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-11 16:01:21.151: E/AndroidRuntime(27694):    ... 4 more
07-11 16:01:21.241: I/Process(27694): Sending signal. PID: 27694 SIG: 9
```

**Here is my php code**

```
public function saveMobileAttachment($imageFile,$userId,$fileName,$fileDescription){
$newRow = $this->createRow();
$buffer = base64_decode($imageFile);
$date = new Zend_Date();
$currentDate = $date->get();
$newRow->FilePath = "attachments/".$currentDate.".jpg";
$file = fopen("attachments/".$currentDate.".jpg", "wb");
fwrite($file, $buffer);  
fclose($file);
$newRow->FileDescription = $fileDescription;
$newRow->FileName = $fileName;
$userAtch = new UserAttachments();
$userAtchRow = $userAtch->createRow();
$userAtchRow->ImageID = $newRow->save();
$userAtchRow->UserID = $userId;
$userAtchRow->save();
}
```

Comment: Make sure that your httpmime.jar  and common-io.jar files are in libs folder

Comment: can you tell me what should be my php code for this ??

Comment: don know about php code but noclassdeferror means that multipartentity class could nt found in your build path

Comment: hmm i have asked new question about php code , hope i will get the answer :(

Comment: give the link of new question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357260/what-should-be-my-php-code-to-upload-pic-to-sever-using-these-lines-of-code/31357312#31357312

Answer (score 1):

NoClassDefFoundError means that it can't find the jar that contains that class.

Since you clearly aren't having any problems compiling your code, that must mean that the jar isn't being included in your APK.

The solution depends on how you are building your app.

If you are using Android Studio, go to File->Project Structure->app->Dependencies and make sure that the apache http library jar is listed.

If you are using Eclipse, go to Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Android Dependencies and make sure the jar is listed. Then go to the Order and Export tab and make sure "Android Dependencies" is checked.

Comment: i have checked , everything is fine , i have added all the jar files and also "Android Dependencies" is checked.:(